# Slow performance when dealing with member api in Umbraco 7.7

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I have the need for a pretty featureless protected page on the site I am working on. It has roughly 9000 members and is completely unusable. Logging in a member can take over 20 seconds. I have tried the default generated login and creating a surfacecontroller where the only code is.

```
Members.Login(model.Username, model.Password)
```

Updating a members password is the same

```
var u = memberService.GetByUsername(model.Username);
string p = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(6, 0);
memberService.SavePassword(u, p);
```

When dealing with the cache the page is quick but as soon as I need a database query specifically dealing with site members the site barely functions.

9000 members does not seem like it should be enough to cause 20 second delays. The members section in the backend works much quicker than the front end (still not quickly but under 10 second) so I do not believe that the number of users is the issue.

The members have no custom properties and there is only one member role and group.

Comment: Is the huge 20s delay solely on the login form post or perhaps the restricted page the user is redirected to after authentication. Umbraco' standard authentication is not particularly fast with lots of users but for a small dataset of 9k you should see no problems. Try logging in, loading the restricted page into cache, logout and back in. Is there still a long page load?

Comment: In case anyone finds this and has a similar problem. I was unfamiliar with umbraco and didn't know it had different database options, the developer that originally set up the site was using a sql compact database witch was obviously not suitable for a site with 9k users. As soon as I switched it out for a MSSQL database the performance was 100% fine.